# Mid 2010s anime with a pink-haired female protagonist who is a robot/cyborg that can turn into or use guns

Tags: story-identification, anime

Does anyone remember or know the name of this anime that has a pink-haired female protagonist that is a robot/cyborg that turns into or can use guns? From what I remember, the girl had a pony tail and a crush on another girl with light purple or similar-coloured hair.

The anime was set in the future and on an island. The protagonist is a girl with robot body parts, and in the beginning, she's seen on a boat in a swimsuit when a woman in a lab coat comes up to her. I think the woman is trying to recruit the girl because she's able to use guns really well due to having robot parts; the woman is a scientist or something like that. She has a magical girl transformation sequence that is explained to be an illusion. The woman's assistant is the pink girl's love interest.

There's one episode where she saves a child from a burning building because she can hold her breath longer, due to being a cyborg/robot. There's a few fight scenes towards the latter half of the anime; I think one involved sneaking into a lab.

I remember watching this series on YouTube around the mid 2010s.

It's not *Valkyrie Drive: Mermaid*.

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Valkyrie Drive: Mermaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie_Drive)*** (2015)...?

[image: Promotional art for "Valkyrie Drive: Mermaid" (2015).]

According to the Wikipedia page, the anime revolves around two types of girls: those who can transform into weapons, known as Extars, and those who have the power to wield an Extar's weapon form, known as Liberators. All these girls are brought to separate islands to keep them isolated from the rest of society.

> Each of the series revolves around girls who have been infected with a mysterious virus known as the A Virus (Armed Virus). **These girls are divided into two classes; Extars (エクスター, Ekusutā), who can transform into weapons when sexually aroused, and Liberators (リブレイター, Ribureitā), who have the power to wield an Extar's weapon form,** known as Liberator Arms, through a process known as Drive. **These girls are brought to separate islands to spend their days completely isolated from the rest of the world** until the islands' Observers, authorized by the government Organisation AAA, ostensibly deem them ready to rejoin society again.

One of the two main protagonists, Mamori Tokonome, is a naïve high schooler with dark pink hair who, as an Extar, can transform into a sword, and later, double-pointed spear.

> The series' protagonist. Mamori is an innocent and naive sixteen-year-old girl who, at a young age, overheard her parents talking about her illness. However, she didn't think much of it until she was abducted and sent to Mermaid island, where she became Mirei's partner. She is often made fun of because her surname is written with the same kanji for "virgin" (処女, shojo). **She is an Extar whose transformation is a large curved sword, though she later gains the power to transform into a double-pointed spear** through the Valkyrie Effect.

The other main protagonist is Mirei Shikishima, a blonde-haired former soldier with implanted nano-cybernetics who, as a Liberator, can wield her weapon form and becomes her lover.

> An observant and intelligent Liberator who becomes Mamori's partner after arriving on the island with her. She doesn't speak much but is very protective of Mamori and is shown to be very powerful. Despite having a mature appearance, she is actually a year younger than Mamori. **She is a former Soldier (code name C7), a member of an experimental military unit** which tested Mirei and her partner's A Virus powers for warfare applications. As a result, **Mirei's body contains a special ability known as Enhance, implanted nano-cybernetics which grant her enhanced strength** but causes a great deal of stress on her body.

Note that the following trailer is NSFW.

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5432596/)*** (2016)...?

> A super-powered terrorist has threatened the island of Cenancle. To fight him off, Nene Nanakorobi, a cybernetic girl-next-door, will have to team up with famous inventor Delilah Uzal and her adorably grumpy cyborg assistant, Clarion.

The main character is Nene Nanakorobi, a 'full-bodied cyborg' who dreams of attaining world peace. She has reddish hair tied in a side tail.

In [episode 1](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5495580/?ref_=ttep_ep1), she's travelling on a cruise liner to the island of Cenancle when she meets a wealthy inventor named Uzal Delilah. Uzal is accompanied by Clarion, who has pink hair, wears a maid's outfit, and introduces herself as Uzal's "prized cyborg pet." Nene has never met another full-bodied cyborg before and is immediately infatuated with Clarion, who doesn't reciprocate her affection.

> [image: Image of Nene, Clarion and Uzal, from "Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn" S01E01.]
>
> <sub>*Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn* - S01E01 - "Adepter"</sub>

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_in_the_Crimson_Shell:_Ghost_Urn), Clarion is a combat android *disguised* as a cyborg, which would explain her relative lack of emotion and synthetic-sounding voice.

> **Clarion** (クラリオン, Kurarion)
> Voiced by: Manami Numakura (Japanese); Lara Woodhull (English)
> **Uzal's companion, who is a combat android, disguising as a full-body cyborg.** Her body holds the Pandora Device, which temporarily grants Nene enhanced abilities. She is a skilled fighter who often finds herself at the mercy of Nene's admiration and hates having her cat-like ears touched.

Later in the episode, Nene sees Uzal and Clarion being attacked by robots controlled by a group of female rebels. Clarion displays great strength and speed whilst battling the robots, but is damaged when she shields Nene from an energy blast. Uzal then transfers an app into Nene that makes her skilled with firearms, and supplies her with guns so that she can help them fight off the robots.

> [image: Image of Nene wielding a gun, from "Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn" S01E01.]
>
> <sub>*Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn* - S01E01 - "Adepter"</sub>

In [episode 8](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8269408/?ref_=ttep_ep8), Nene and Clarion are visiting a department store when a fire breaks out. Nene sees a small boy trapped on a higher floor and goes off to save him without Clarion, who thinks they should escape immediately. Nene reaches the boy, who's struggling to breathe, and uses mouth-to-mouth to pass most of her internal oxygen supply to him. She herself is on the verge of passing out as a result of this, but luckily, both of them are saved by Clarion.

> [image: Image of Nene trying to save a small boy in a burning building, from "Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn" S01E08.]
>
> <sub>*Pandora in the Crimson Shell: Ghost Urn* - S01E08 - "Inferno"</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Battle Doll Angelic Layer?

https://myanimelist.net/anime/52/Kidou_Tenshi_Angelic_Layer

Aired from Apr 1, 2001 to Sep 23, 2001

See if this rings any bells: