# Anime About Robot Girls Fighting

Tags: story-identification, anime

Early 2010s anime about a girl with pink hair that looks like a doll and from my memory had a ponytail and a female love interest that was a maid or assistant. I cannot remember the name at all, however, I do remember watching it on YouTube in the early 2010s. In the first episode the protagonist is a female who looks like a doll and is on a yacht in a bikini when a woman comes up to her and talks to her.

I also believe there was another episode where the protagonist saves a child from a burning building because she’s able to be in the smoke for longer due to having robotic parts.

The anime does have fighting scenes, I think the woman from the first episode is trying to recruit the pink haired girl to fight some other robot girls.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannazuki_no_Miko?

Comment: @Shortie - Are you the same user who posted [this similar-sounding question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/283804/122024) a few days ago? If so, we'd appreciate it if you'd [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can interact with your previous question, especially if it's asking about the same anime as this one.